# Bidi package messing up line spacing in XeLaTeX

Tags: spacing, xetex, footnotes, bidi

I need to use XeLaTeX with the `bidi` package in my document. However, after long testing, it turned out that `bidi` somehow allows `setspace` to modify the line spacing of the footnotes, but keeps the spacing between footnotes the same, thus creating uneven spacing. See my example below with a picture:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{\lipsum[3]}
\end{document}
```

[image: Uneven spacing]

How would it be possible to restore the original spacing in the footnotes?

Answer (score 2):

The `setspace` package inserts the following into `\@footnotetext` to ensure that footnotes are single spaced:

```
\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}
```

We can use hooks provided by `bidi` to do the same for it's three kinds of footnotes.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bidi}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bidi@@footnotetext@font}{%
  \def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
  \footnotesize}
\renewcommand*{\bidi@@LTRfootnotetext@font}{%
  \def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
  \footnotesize}
\renewcommand*{\bidi@@RTLfootnotetext@font}{%
  \def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
  \footnotesize}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[4]}

\lipsum[2]\footnote{\lipsum[3]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you load setspace after bidi you overwrite the special \@footnotetext definition of bidi.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, hmm. Good call. As I look more closely, `bidi` includes a helpful hook that can be used to set the spacing pretty easily. I'll change my answer.